# R object is not a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am new to R and trying to save my svm model in R and have read the documentation but still do not understand what is wrong.

I am getting the error "object is not a matrix" which would seem to mean that my data is not a matrix, but it is... so something is missing.

My data is defined as:

```
data = read.table("data.csv")
trainSet = as.data.frame(data[,1:(ncol(data)-1)])
```

Where the last line is my label

I am trying to define my model as:

```
svm.model <- svm(type ~ ., data=trainSet, type='C-classification', kernel='polynomial',scale=FALSE)
```

This seems like it should be correct but I am having trouble finding other examples.

Here is my code so far:

```
# load libraries
require(e1071)
require(pracma)
require(kernlab)
options(warn=-1)

# load dataset
SVMtimes = 1
KERNEL="polynomial"
DEGREE = 2
data = read.table("head.csv")
results10foldAll=c()

# Cross Fold for training and validation datasets
for(timesRun in 1:SVMtimes) {
    cat("Running SVM = ",timesRun," result = ")

    trainSet = as.data.frame(data[,1:(ncol(data)-1)])
    trainClasses = as.factor(data[,ncol(data)])
    model = svm(trainSet, trainClasses, type="C-classification", 
                kernel = KERNEL, degree = DEGREE, coef0=1, cost=1, 
                cachesize = 10000, cross = 10)
    accAll = model$accuracies
    cat(mean(accAll), "/", sd(accAll),"\n")

    results10foldAll = rbind(results10foldAll, c(mean(accAll),sd(accAll)))
 }


# create model

svm.model <- svm(type ~ ., data = trainSet, type='C-classification', kernel='polynomial',scale=FALSE)
```

An example of one of my samples would be:

```
10.135338 7.214543 5.758917 6.361316 0.000000 18.455875 14.082668  31
```

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible example. Is the `svm` function (from what package?) expecting the "data" argument to be a matrix? If so, that's your problem. `read.table` imports data as data.frame objects, which are higher-level constructions. Try `data = as.matrix(trainSet)`.

Comment: @jdobres this is from the e1071 package.  I added my current code.  My dataset is really big but I gave an example line.  My dataset actually has about 3,000 features for each sample so I simplified  here.

Comment: are you getting error when using `model.matrix()` or more like `sparse.model.matrix()` (because of your bigger data size). One tip when using `sparse.model.matrix()` before `svm()` do standardize the data in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, **trainSet** is a data frame but in the **svm.model** function it expects **data** to be a matrix(where you are assigning **trainSet** to data). Hence, set **data = as.matrix(trainSet)**. This should work fine.

Comment: That makes sense but it didn't work either                     Error in model.frame.default(formula = type ~ ., data = list(V1 = c(21.933418,  : 
  object is not a matrix

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as pointed out by @user5196900 you need a matrix to run the `svm()`. However beware that matrix object means all columns have same datatypes, all numeric or all categorical/factors. If this is true for your data `as.matrix()` may be fine.

In practice more than often people want to `model.matrix()` or `sparse.model.matrix()` (from package `Matrix`) which gives dummy columns for categorical variables, while having single column for numerical variables. But a matrix indeed.